# Изменение свойств текста в ListPreference

Tags: list, android, java

Подскажите как изменять размер, шрифт и размер текста. Как это лучше и правильнее сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте класс наследующий  ListPreference. Посмотрите это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4557852